# Appeasement or appeasing?

Tags: grammar

I read an article in "The Hindu" which was  titled as -

> An appeasement budget

Should not budget be preceded by "appeasing" instead of "appeasement"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it could be a writing style where a noun serves as an adjective. Something like...

> A boat race

'boat' is a noun, working there as an adjective.

> An appeasement budget

'appeasement' is a noun, working there as an adjective.

[A good read is here.](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm)

Comment: This is called an **adjuct** or **attributive** noun, where one noun indicates an attribute of another. In this case, a budget which has appeasement as a purpose.